# How to use @Value inside @Pattern

Tags: java, spring, validation, annotations

How can I use a application config value inside a @Pattern?

Here a (not working) example:

```
    @GetMapping(value = "/foo", params = { "id" })
    public Foo getFoo(@RequestParam("id") @Pattern(regexp = @Value("${validation.myRegex}")) String id) {
        return null;
    }
```

And this is also not working (mentioned by Eklavya):

```
    @GetMapping(value = "/foo", params = { "id" })
    public Foo getFoo(@RequestParam("id") @Pattern(regexp = "${validation.myRegex}") String id) {
        return null;
    }
```

If I use it like this, it works: `fooBar(@Value("${validation.myRegex}") String myRegex)` So the question is how to use the value for the pattern annotation?

My application.yaml looks like this:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: 'My Awesome App'
validation:
  myRegex: '[a-zA-Z0-9]*'
```

Comment: If you reading from properties file then `@Pattern(regexp = "${myRegex}")`(with proper path like data.const.regex) or declare the constraint [programmatically](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#section-fail-fast)

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn`t work. I updated the question with some more information / code